# What does Python random.shuffle()'s second argument do?

Tags: python, random

According to the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.shuffle),

> **random.shuffle(x[, random])**
>
> Shuffle the sequence x in place. The optional argument random is a
> 0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by
> default, this is the function random().
>
> Note that for even rather small len(x), the total number of
> permutations of x is larger than the period of most random number
> generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can
> never be generated.

Even after reading this, I still don't understand what is the role of the "random" argument.
Also, why on earth the argument form is (x[, random]), not (x, random)? what is that bracket and comma?

Sorry for the stupid question...

Comment: As a side note, the `random` parameter is deprecated since Python 3.9 and will be removed from Python 3.11

Comment: @Guy Oh, will there be any substitute for the random module?

Comment: The module remains, the parameter in `shuffle` is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Checking [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/random.py#L264-L284) for `shuffle`, we can see that `shuffle` iterates through the list and swaps each item in the list with another random item in the list. The `random` function is used to get that random element with which to switch the current element.

For example, if you set `random` to a function that always returns 0, each element will be swapped with the first element in the list:

```
from random import shuffle

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
shuffle(l, lambda: 0)
print(l)
>>> [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to rely on function internals unless they have been explicitly specified in the documentation. However, it can be handy to always create the same order for the same runtime, e.g. for testing purposes. Another use case would be providing another random number generator (faster, more secure, etc.) to the `shuffle` function.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes your comment sounds suspiciously AI-generated. How does it relate to the question of what the `random` argument does?

Comment: Really? I'm fighting AI generated content as a moderator and I would immediately find indications that above is not AI generated. For instance, the "e.g." and double use of the word "another" are clear indications that AI didn't generate it. Yes, I'm somewhat wordy and used "However,", but that's just how the English language is supposed to work. So, uh, thanks I guess. I think my remark is very on topic, is about using the `random` parameter. It is also just a comment, I *did* vote up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bracket and comma are just a standard documentation notation for saying "this parameter is optional".  You wouldn't use the brackets when making the call.

The documentation seems pretty clear.  You can provide your own random number function, if you want to.  With shuffle, it's hard to come up with a good justification for this.

By default, this:

```
random.shuffle(lst)
```

is the same as

```
random.shuffle(lst, random.random)
```